# pi 4 freezing when i try to open openshot or vlc media player

Tags: pi-4

I have watched my cpu and memory usage when try to open these apps cpu  does not go above 20 % memory stays in the hundreds. I also tested my sd card and it passed. I have this problem with two units.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=275489

Comment: Thank you Dougie I am not having problem watching video. My system freezes when i try to open ether one of the above listed programs.